# Computing projection onto the following closed convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, convex-geometry, projection

Let $\mathbf{S}^n$ denote the space of symmetric, real-valued $n \times n$ matrices.

Consider the closed convex set

$$
\mathcal{C} := \{(X, x) \in \mathbf{S}^n \times \mathbf{R}^n : X \succeq xx^T, ~ \mathbf{tr}(X) \leq 1\},$$
where $\succeq$ above denotes the positive semidefinite (Lowner) order, and $\mathbf{tr}(\cdot)$ denotes trace.

I would like to compute the Euclidean projection onto this set, i.e., I wonder if there is a closed form for the following operator, $\mathrm{proj}: \mathbf{S}^n \times \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathcal{C}$, which is variationally given by 
$$
\mathrm{proj}(Z, z) = {\mathrm{argmin}}_{(X, x) \in \mathcal{C}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\|Z - X\|_F^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|z - x\|_2^2 \right),
$$
where above $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Nice Problem! May I ask the real world application

Answer (score 0):

First note since $
X \succeq xx^T \Leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
    X       & x \\
    x^T     & 1
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$, it makes sense to look at the problem as one in $S^{n+1}$.
Let $P_1, P_2$ be linear projections from $S^{n+1}$ to $S^{n} \times R^n$ and $R$ respectively:
$$
P_1 \left( \begin{bmatrix}
    X       & x \\
    x^T     & y
\end{bmatrix} \right) := (X,x), \quad 
P_2 \left( \begin{bmatrix}
    X       & x \\
    x^T     & y 
\end{bmatrix} \right) := y
$$

So then define the subsets of $S^{n+1}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_1 &:= \{ W \in S^{n+1} : W \succeq 0, ~ tr(W) \le 2\}\\
D_2 &:= \{ W \in S^{n+1} : P_2(W) = 1\}
\end{aligned}
$$
Then the intersection of these is equivalent to $C$ in the following sense:
$$
(X,x) \in C \Leftrightarrow P_1^T(X,x) + P_2^T(1) \in D_1 \cap D_2
$$
Note that it is possible to project onto $D_1$ using eigenvalue decomposition and projection onto $D_2$ is trivial, since it's just a plane. So we can almost get a closed form expression for the projection onto the intersection.

Using the notation $
\Pi_A (z) = \mathrm{argmin}_{x \in A} \|x-z\|^2
$ for nonlinear projection onto a set, we have:

$$
\Pi_C (Z,z) = P_1\left( \Pi_{D_1} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
    Z       & z \\
    z^T     & y^*
\end{bmatrix} \right) \right)
$$
Where $y^*$ is the value satisfies the following:
$$
1 = P_2\left( \Pi_{D_1} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
    Z       & z \\
    z^T     & y^* 
\end{bmatrix} \right) \right)
$$
This can be solved numerically via a 1-dimensional root-finding method. I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid calculating a full eigenvalue decomposition every time you project onto to $D_1$.